# Android datepicker spinner text color styling

Tags: android, android-styles

I'm using a spinner date picker and using the `Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog` parent theme. How do I set the text color for "Set date", "Cancel" & "Set" here?

xml attributes:

```
  <style name="SpinnerDatePickerDialogDark" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <item name="colorAccent">@color/white</item>
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@color/gray_10</item>
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@color/gray_02</item>
    <item name="android:textColorSecondary">@color/white</item>
    <!-- Divider color -->
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@color/gray_02</item>
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/SpinnerDatePicker</item>
  </style>

  <style name="SpinnerDatePicker" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
  </style>
```

[image: Date picker spinner]

Comment: Full guide is here: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/docs/components/DatePicker.md.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To change the text color for "Cancel" and "Set" buttons you can use a custom dialog button style using the attribute  `android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle` for the Positive Button and `android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle` for the Negative Button. To change the header text color for "Set date" you can simply use the `android:textColor` attribute.

Define in your `style.xml` the below `SpinnerDatePickerDialogStyle`:

```
<style name="SpinnerDatePickerDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog">
    <!--This will change the window dialog background color-->
    <item name="android:windowBackground">@android:color/black</item>
    <!-- This will change the date picker Day/Month/Year Text color-->
    <item name="android:textColorPrimary">@android:color/holo_green_dark</item>
    <!-- This will change the divider color -->
    <item name="android:colorControlNormal">@android:color/holo_orange_dark</item>
    <!-- This will set a custom style to the Date Picker eg: spinner mode style -->
    <item name="android:datePickerStyle">@style/MySpinnerDatePickerStyle</item>
    <!-- This will set a custom style to the dialog Button Positive-->
    <item name="android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle">@style/MyDatePickerButtonStyle</item>
    <!-- This will set a custom style to the dialog Button Negative-->
    <item name="android:buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle">@style/MyDatePickerButtonStyle</item>
    <!-- This will change the dialog Title Text color -->
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_red_dark</item>
</style>

<!-- Custom  DatePicker Style-->
<style name="MySpinnerDatePickerStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.DatePicker">
    <item name="android:datePickerMode">spinner</item>
</style>

<!-- Custom DatePicker Button Style-->
<style name="MyDatePickerButtonStyle" parent="android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless">
    <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/holo_blue_light</item>
</style>
```

And use the above style like below:

```
DatePickerDialog datePickerDialog = new DatePickerDialog(context, R.style.SpinnerDatePickerDialogStyle,
        new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener(){
            @Override
            public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year, int month, int dayOfMonth) {

            }
        },
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.YEAR),
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.MONTH),
        Calendar.getInstance().get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
datePickerDialog.setTitle("Set Date");
datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_POSITIVE, "SET", datePickerDialog);
datePickerDialog.setButton(DatePickerDialog.BUTTON_NEGATIVE, "CANCEL", datePickerDialog);
datePickerDialog.show();
```

**Result:**

[image: date_picker_dialog]

Comment: Thanks, that works! Is there a way to see that the attribute `android:buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle` is available for the component?

Comment: By default the two dialog buttons internally they have a custom style like style="?attr/buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle" and  style="?attr/buttonBarNegativeButtonStyle" in the default inflated xml like this alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml (https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/master/core/res/res/layout/alert_dialog_button_bar_material.xml)  so you need to override them using your custom styles. Official documentation for buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle is https://developer.android.com/reference/android/R.attr#buttonBarPositiveButtonStyle.